# Why is functional faster than imperative for large amounts of data and slower than imperative for small amounts of data?

Tags: java, performance, arraylist, functional-programming, java-stream

I wanted to compare the performance of loops to streams. For this I wrote 2 methods. Both filter out names beginning with 'A' and return them in a String.
If I do this with 50.000 randomly generated names, the imperative way is faster. But if I do this with 500.000 randomly generated names, the functional way is faster.

My question is why is the functional paradigm slower for small data sets and faster for large data sets? Do streams need a lot of time to initialize but after this they are more efficient?

```
public String imperativeArray() {

String result = "";
  for(String name : arraytestSet) {
    if(name.startsWith("A")) {
       if(result.isEmpty()) {
          result += name;
       } else {
          result += "," + name;
       }
    }
  }
   return result;
}

public String functionalArray() {
   return Arrays.stream(arraytestSet)
     .filter(e -> e.startsWith("A"))
     .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
}
```

Comment: For one thing, because you are using naive string concatenation in the imperative case. Try using a `StringBuilder` instead.

Comment: When dealing with small numbers the iterative solution should be better because the of the overhead of creating a stream. Under the hood the stream is breaking your problem up into smaller pieces and executing them, but this is only a benefit on large data sets.

Comment: @AndyTurner I know in some cases the java compiler will use a StringBuilder if it sees concatenation. Does this not work in loops?

Comment: @SamOrozco no..

Comment: The compiler can't recognize that it would be more effective to have ONE string builder for all of the loop. It will create a new stringbuilder for each if and else branch execution! When in doubt, run javap and look at the bytecode!

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn’t be any performance difference between imperative and functional. Functional programming will improve readability of code by using predefined functions. Internally they must do similar type of processing. One of the main advantages of functional style is that you can understand the code with a single glance at it.
Parallel streams can be faster than your imperative code but Parallel stream can be used if you are sure that the data will be huge and gets benefit from parallel processing. Otherwise parallel stream would be slower than normal stream. 
Coming to your sample code, I feel that by using Collectors.joining you are getting a performance benefit than the if-else check because you are using string append operation which will keep on creating a new string object everytime it appends. But collectors.joining internally uses StringBuilder and so it will work on a single object every time it appends.